# PostgreSQL syntax error related to INSERT and/or WITH. Occurs in 8.4 but not 9.1. Ideas?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-insert, postgresql-8.4

Here is some SQL for PostgreSQL (I know it's a silly query; I've boiled the original query down to the simplest broken code):

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

  WITH new_entity
    AS (INSERT INTO entity DEFAULT VALUES
          RETURNING id
       )
SELECT id FROM new_entity;
```

Here it is running on PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
psql:../sandbox/test.sql:3: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "entity_id_seq" for serial column "entity.id"
psql:../sandbox/test.sql:3: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "entity_pkey" for table "entity"
CREATE TABLE
 id 
----
  1
(1 row)
```

Here it is not running on PostgreSQL 8.4:

```
psql:../sandbox/test.sql:3: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "entity_id_seq" for serial column "entity.id"
psql:../sandbox/test.sql:3: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "entity_pkey" for table "entity"
CREATE TABLE
psql:../sandbox/test.sql:9: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 2:   AS (INSERT INTO entity DEFAULT VALUES
```

Obviously, the table creation goes fine in both cases, but it wipes out on the second query in PostgreSQL 8.4. From this error message I am unable to gather exactly what the problem is. I don't know what it is that 9.1 has and 8.4 doesn't have that could result in this syntax error. It's hilariously hard to [google it](https://www.google.ca/search?q=syntax%20error%20at%20or%20near%20insert%20with%20as). I am approaching the level of desperation required to trawl through the pages of PostgreSQL release notes between 8.4 and 9.1 and finding out if anything related to `WITH … AS` or `INSERT … RETURNING` was changed or added, but before I go there I am hoping one of you has the experience and/or godly google-fu to help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data-modifying statements in WITH were introduced in Postgres 9.1

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I'm splitting that second statement into two for 8.4 compatibility.